# Generation random words in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm attempting to make a poll in Django which takes words from a text file (a list of words) to generate the question. For example, the question will be: How do you like "Pizza"? The word in " " will change everytime the question is answered. I have everything set up besides the random word.

I wrote a view to randomly select a word and store it in an array.

```
def selection(request):
           j = []
       with open('textFiles/food.txt', 'r') as f:
         for rida in f:
             rida = rida.rstrip()
            if rida: j.append(rida)
          else: break

       i = j[(randrange(0,4))]
```

My question is: How do I implement 'i', which is my random word, into the template to display the sentence? Do I need to write another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `i` into the context that you use to render the HTML output. Then you can access it with the syntax `{{ i }}` inside the template.

At the end of your view:

```
return render("some_template.html", {'i': i})
```

and in the view:

```
<p>Do you like {{ i }}?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template tag.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Comment: Haven't created any custom tags yet. I will have to look into it.